Installing the hive on windows
C:\Users\hp>cd C:\hive\bin
C:\hive\bin>hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute(WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java:358)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:496)
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:136)
at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(TempFileHelper.java:173)
at java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Files.java:950)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:245)
I want to install the hive on the windows and i am getting this error
